# Nginx setup with multiple html files

Tags: html, nginx, deployment

I have got a website with multiple html files which I want to serve with Nginx.

```
server {
        listen 80;
        root /var/www;
        location / {
                index index.html;
        }

        location /projects/ {
                index projects.html;
        }

        server_name mylady17.de;


        location /shiny/ {
                proxy_pass http://104.248.41.231:3838/;
        }
}
```

This is the way it is set up. The index.html works perfectly fine, but however `"http://mylady17.de/projects"` gives me an error (404, not found). The `projects.html` file is stored in `var/www/` and should work. What am I doing wrong? Why can´t I access the file?

Comment: So you want the URI `/projects` to return the file `/var/www/projects.html`. Is this just one file or a general rule for a number of html files on your site?

Comment: Yes excactly! It is just a single file. Nothing complicated ;-)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `index` directive operates on URIs which end with a `/` and attempt to locate files by appending the value of the directive to the URI. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_index_module.html#index) for details.

So your URI `/projects` will not invoke the index module. Even if you did use `/projects/` instead, the index module would attempt to locate the file at `/var/www/projects/projects.html`.

---

To point a single URI to a given file, you can use an exact match `location`. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#location) for details.

For example:

```
location = /projects {
    rewrite ^ /projects.html last;
}
```

---

If you did decide to expand this in the future, requiring `nginx` to search for files by appending `.html` to the end of the URI, you could use a `try_files` directive instead. See [this document](http://nginx.org/en/docs/http/ngx_http_core_module.html#try_files) for details.

For example:

```
location / {
    try_files $uri $uri/ $uri.html =404;
}
```

Comment: works perfectly, thank you so much. For the help and the explanantion.

Comment: I would advise against using an `index` directive and a `try_files` directive together like this as the `index` directive performs an internal redirect. It wouldn't cause an issue here as Richard has specified `=404` as the final parameter of his `try_files`, but without that it's easy to end up with logs like this: `[error] 11111#11111: *308181 rewrite or internal redirection cycle while internally redirecting to "/path/.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html.html"`. Instead you can add `$uri/index.html` to the `try_files` directive to achieve the same result

Comment: Also worth noting if you are new to Nginx that you should only ever use location blocks without a trailing slash in the way Richard has outlined, specifying an exact match with the `=` modifier. Otherwise requests to `/projectsurveys`, `/projectspecs/` etc will also be served from the `/projects` location block, assuming there is no better match